# What events can I use to monitor users typing in Word?

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

I'm trying to write some code which executes as you type in Word.

Which events should I observe to catch individual words or characters? Ideally I'd rather not observe keystrokes through some dll calls. I assumed the Word object model would expose some classes with native VBA events, but the only two event objects:

```
Word.Document
Word.Application
```

don't have any events that leap out at me. (`Document_Change` event doesn't seem to do what I want)

**Is there a native way of executing a code when the text content of the document changes?**

Answer (score 1):

Word provides *no* events for capturing the user's typing.

That leaves:

- "keyboard hooks" at the Windows API level.
- Or assigning a VBA macro to each and every possible key combination
  (a `KeyBinding`).