# Run macro when something changes

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to call a macro automatically in Microsoft Word when I change something?

For example, I want to call the macro 'Tester' when I change anything.

```
Sub Tester()
    Call Msgbox("Something has changed")
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929187/word-vba-event-for-detecting-text-change-in-the-document

Comment: See Cindy Meister's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338375/what-events-can-i-use-to-monitor-users-typing-in-word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What events can I use to monitor users typing in Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338375/what-events-can-i-use-to-monitor-users-typing-in-word)