# Conditional formatting on Word table cells, auto run after every cell value change

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Risk Assessment form template, and would like it so that in all tables within the document, when numbers are changed within the tables, they change colour dependent on the value.

I've had a good stab at it, but can only get it to change colour for one selected table at a time, and don't know how to make it automatically 'run' after every change to the tables.

Here's what I've got so far:

```vb
Sub ColourAllTables()
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oCell As Cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each oCell In oTable.Range.Cells
            Select Case Split(c.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
            Case 1: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
            Case 2: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
            Case 3: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
            Case 4: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 5: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 6: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 7: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 8: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 9: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 10: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 11: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 12: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 13: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 14: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 15: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 16: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 17: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 18: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 19: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 20: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 21: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 22: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 23: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 24: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case 25: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case Else: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
            End Select
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255405/run-macro-when-something-changes) from 3 days ago about making something run whenever there is a change.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest solution would be to use Excel's conditional formatting.

However, it is possible to build a events system for table cells in word.
The code being quite large, I put it in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/viccol961/acb4f80d7a1594b485d3f72223f3333c).

I also uploaded a demo document [here](https://gist.github.com/viccol961/acb4f80d7a1594b485d3f72223f3333c/raw/db0b7217e50bb8a4d43fb70907028f7cc0839e91/CellEventsManagerDemo.docm).

---

I tried to comment the code as much as possible to ease comprehesion.

To use, define each event's behavior by modifying the `EventManager` subroutine in the `CellEventsManagerModule` module.

Even if I would recommend trying to understand the entire code (it's a good exercice!), I don't think you need to.
You can just focus on the `EventManager` subroutine and the example I provided.

It should not be too difficult to implement your solution, but if you encounter problems while doing so, don't hesitate to ask for help in the comments!

---

On a side note, the `Select Case` syntax has a better solution for what you're trying to do. The following is equivalent to your code:

```
Select Case Split(c.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
    Case 1 To 3: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
    Case 4 To 10: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
    Case 11 To 25: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
    Case Else: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
End Select
```

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) out for more info on the Select Case syntax!

Comment: @laura Did you get the chance to try either solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi @vic.col961, Thank-you so much for taking the time to look at this for me. I'll be honest, I haven't got it to work just yet, but I'll try and plug away at it for a few days :) so big thanks! Hoping to find a colleague who can make better sense of it all so your hard work isn't wasted :) All the best, Laura