# Detecting when data is added to a document, eg. a character or white space

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to detect when a user presses a key in Microsoft Word using VBA. I have searched for a method which does this. I have also searched for methods which create a way around this, such as detecting when the insertion point moves or it detects when a new character is placed in the word document, but I have had no look. I am currently using `appWord_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)` but this does not detect as you type.

I would appreciate anyone showing me how to either detect a keypress or would be able to show me a workaround which will accomplish the same goal.

**Edit**

I apologise if the summary of what I want above is not clear. What I have is a sub which fires using `appWord_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)`. However what I want is this sub to fire whenever any data is entered into the word document, eg. a letter or a white space character. For example, if there was a character count in the footer of the word document and this sub which I have updates this character count, the character count field should update as the user types in the document.

Comment: You can use the Windows API to detect key presses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell

Comment: you may try autohotkey too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470984/capturing-keydown-event-of-ms-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not my Code but HTH.

```
        Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
        Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

        Sub KeyStrokeLogger()
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim KeyAsciiValue As Integer

            StartLogging
            Do While True
                For i = 1 To 255
                    If GetAsyncKeyState(i) = -32767 Then
                        If CapsLockIsOn() Then
                            If ShiftIsPressed() = True Then
                 KeyAsciiValue = Asc(LCase(Chr(i)))
                  Else
                 KeyAsciiValue = Asc(UCase(Chr(i)))
                  End If
                        Else
                            If ShiftIsPressed() = True Then
                 KeyAsciiValue = Asc(UCase(Chr(i)))
                  Else
                 KeyAsciiValue = Asc(LCase(Chr(i)))
                  End If
                        End If
                        LogKeyStroke KeyAsciiValue
                    End If
                Next i
                DoEvents
            Loop
        End Sub

        Private Function CapsLockIsOn() As Boolean
            CapsLockIsOn = CBool(GetKeyState(20))
        End Function

        Private Function ShiftIsPressed() As Boolean
            ShiftIsPressed = CBool(GetAsyncKeyState(16))
        End Function

        Private Sub StartLogging()
            Open "C:\keylog.txt" For Binary As #1
            Seek #1, LOF(1) + 1
        End Sub

        Private Sub LogKeyStroke(KeyAsciiValue As Integer)
            Dim c As String * 1
            c = Chr(KeyAsciiValue)
            Select Case KeyAsciiValue
                Case 8
                    Put #1, , "{BACKSPACE}"
                Case 9
                    Put #1, , "{TAB}"
                Case 13
                    Put #1, , "{ENTER}"
                Case 32 To 126
                    Put #1, , c
                Case Else
                    Put #1, , "{" & KeyAsciiValue & "}"
            End Select
        End Sub
```

*"How to use the above code:

Step 1
Create a new document in MS-Word.

Step 2
Go to Tools, Macro, Visual Basic Editor

Step 3
Double click on ThisDocument Object under Project(Document1) in the Project Window.

Step 4
Copy the above code and paste it into the Visual Basic Editor.

Step 5
Close the Visual Basic Editor and save the document.

Step 6
Ensure that macros are enabled. To start logging keystrokes at any time click on Tools, Macro, Macros. Select KeyStrokeLogger and click Run. All the keystrokes will be stored in C:\keylog.txt.
"*
[LinkBack to Post](http://www.enigmagroup.org/forums/visual-basic/simple-keystroke-logger-program-using-ms-word/)

Comment: With a little editing, I found out how to make it run a macro when it picked up a keystroke instead of recording it to a `.txt` file. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use keybindings to bind characters to the function you want. For example, the following code (when run) fires a message box when the user enters 0 in the word document.

Put this in module 1

```
Sub AddKeyBinding()
With Application
    .CustomizationContext = ThisDocument
    .KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKey0), _
    KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
    Command:="userpressedzero"
End With
End Sub
```

Put this in module 2

```
Sub userpressedzero()
    Dim MyText As String
    Selection.TypeText ("0")
    MsgBox ("user pressed 0")
End Sub
```

Now run module 1 and press 0 in your word document.